# 時系列データのパターンマッチングについて

Tags: python, pandas, 機械学習

時系列データのパターンマッチングについて

ある時系列データ(a)に、あらかじめ指定したパターンデータ(b)と似た形が、
どの時期にどの程度含まれているか、相関関係を求めたいのですが、
どのようなアプローチがよいでしょうか？（以下の方法は適切でしょうか？）

◇想定しているデータ
(a)時系列データ
時系列データは、音声データ、株価データなどを想定しています。
インデックスはpd.Timestamp型です。

(b)パターンデータ
上記(a)と同様な時系列データです。
インデックスはpd.Timestamp型ですが、上記(a)の時系列データよりは期間が短くなっています。

◇やりたいこと
パターンデータ(b)の
時期をずらしたもの（左右方向へ平行移動させたもの）、
および周期を変更したもの（左右方向へ拡大/縮小したもの）
も、相関係数算出の対象としたいです。
なお上下方向は、正規化or標準化します。

◇やろうとしていること
1.pd.resample関数を利用する。
時系列データ(a)と、パターンデータ(b)のTimestampインデックスを同じ単位に揃える（例えば日ごと、秒ごとなど）
2.パターンデータ(b)のindexを変更する。
時系列データ(a)の先頭行の日付になるよう、パターンデータ(b)のindexを変更する。
3.pd.corr関数を利用する。
相関係数を算出算出する。
4.以降同様に、パターンデータ(b)のindexを１単位時間後（１日後など）にずらし、2.～3.の手順を繰り返し、相関関数を算出する。
5.以降同様に、パターンデータの期間を拡大/縮小し、2.～4.の手順を繰り返す。
6.結果の集計
各時期ごと（日ごと）に、相関係数の最大値と、そのときの日付、およびパターンデータ(b)の拡大/縮小率を、算出結果とする。

GoogleColab + PandasのDataFrameで試しています。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 実行結果のサンプル]

記載した方法でやってみました。とりあえず望みの結果が得られました。
パフォーマンスなど改善点はまだまだありますが、いったんCloseいたします。
ありがとうございました。